# How to use Google Content Experiment with Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-experiments, content-experiments

I couldn't find any answers on how to use/implement Google Content Experiments with GTM.

I currently have set-up a GTM container with GA code and in the original page for the experiment i have the Google Experiment Code at the beginning of the html tag.
The problem I'm having is that not all users are counted in Google Analytics Experiments Report.

- Is it still impossible to use Google Content Experiments in GTM? ([How to run Google Experiment within Google Tag Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23575878/how-to-run-google-experiment-within-google-tag-manager) - seems a bit old discussion)
- What is the best way of implementing the experiment code in Tag Manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still impossible to implement Google Experiments with GTM.

However as far as I understand - you implemented the experiment code in the normal way. Did you checked if the experiment is set for 100% of your visitors? If it's less - it's normal to get some visits outside of the experiment and it sounds like this is the case with you.

Other than that - the GTM shouldn't affect the experiment itself in any way, as you don't use GTM for it.