# Google Tag Manager - AB split testing

Tags: testing, tags, google-tag-manager

I want to test two completely different versions of my homepage using A/B split testing in Google Tag Manager. I can do this using Google Analytics, but I am working on a site that uses Google Tag Manager. I have found several guides helping me to create a split test that uses Jquery to change a single element on a page, but no mention of testing two separate versions of the same page.

Does anybody know how to split test two versions of a page?

Answer (score 1):

As you probably know there is something called [Content Experiments](https://analytics.googleblog.com/2012/06/helping-to-create-better-websites.html) in GA. Which gives you the possibility to show different variations of pages to your visitors. This would seem to do the trick for you if you want to know which page works best. All info is being tracked in your GA.

I've also been searching how to implement this with GTM but with no luck so far. I did find [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31416731/6574757) [posts/answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23581833/6574757)  here on Stackoverflow.

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention that Google [Optimize](https://www.google.com/analytics/optimize/features/) also might be very interesting of what I've read. Unfortunately at this time it's still in Beta and you have to sign up to get added to a list. I assume it's first come, first serve so you have to wait your turn to get access to the Beta.