# Is it OK (in google analytics) o have some pages with the GTM and others with analytics.js?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, analytics.js

Per my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33289795/4906)  I have some pages using Google Tag Manager to report Google Analytics and some that report them directly using Analytics.js.

It seems to be working OK but I wanted to see if there were any issues I should be aware of.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to make sure that whatever you are tracking with on-page code on those pages that don't have GTM are not already being tracked through GTM.

Generally speaking, it's not advisable to mix both GA and GTM on the same site (unless you are in the middle of migrating one to the other). So either go all GA, or all GTM (I usually always recommend going GTM). Otherwise there could be conflicts. It goes without saying that you should always test everything, too.

Comment: It is perfectly OK mixing tracking methods if makes sense to you. E.g. private section of a website, where I don't want to have any 3rd party library/tool such as gtm or analytics.js. There I host analytics.js locally. On a public part of a web I can have GTM, because I don't care so much about security. Finally, you can use Mesurement Protocol from your external devices or emailing... All of it (ga hardcoded, GTM, Emailing) is just a data source...